# Is Prussia dying?

Tags: hetalia

In a Hetalia manga strip, Germany notices a dog bite on Prussia's hand. Germany says it'll heal later.

However, the dog was thinking, "Didn't I bite him last week?"

Another manga strip shows him coughing up blood.

But, he doesn't seem to　age.

Answer (score 1):

No one really knows for sure. It's possible, because the actual nation of Prussia hasn't existed for a long time. The personified nations are apparently immortal, until the actual nations disappear. Grandpa Rome and (maybe) HRE are both dead, but Grandpa Rome still visits nations as a spirit. So it could happen, but since Prussia is a fan favorite, it's unlikely.